# T-SQL - Best way to select rows that corresponds to a category and default category if the category is not configured

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of configuration data that can be associated to a Recipe (category to be more generic).

Like this:

Recipes:

```
ID Name
1 Default
2 A
3 B
```

Configuration Data

```
ID equipment ParentID RecipeID
1  3420      1         1 
2  3420      1         2
3  3421      1         1
4  3421      1         2
5  3422      1         1
```

I want to know how I could select all configuration Data for recipe "A", and fall back on "Default" values if recipe A is not configured for a Configuration Data Row.  Then I would get this:

```
ID equipment ParentID RecipeID
2  3420      1         2
4  3421      1         2
5  3422      1         1
```

I already found something like this but I am unsure it is a good approach:

```
select * from ConfigurationData
where RecipeID=2 and parentID=1
union 
select * from ConfigurationData
where RecipeID=1 and parentID=1
and Equipment not in (select Equipment from ConfigurationData 
where RecipeID=2 and parentID=1)
```

Comment: what query have you written so far? Please share.

Comment: The Default Recipe is mandatory in the system.

Comment: Will all equipment be used, so is the query. from configuration data pick 1 row for each equipment, either the matching recipe id or the default if no match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using a CTE?

```
/** 
 * first declare an id to search for
 */
declare @recipeId int 

set @recipeId = 2 -- Change this to the recipe you want to select

/**
 * Now the actual query
 */
with cte as (
  select r.id as Recipe, c.id, c.equipment, c.recipeid, row_number() over (partition by r.id, c.equipment order by c.RecipeId desc) as row
  from
       recipes r inner join configuration c on r.id = c.recipeid or c.recipeid = 1
)
select
   id, equipment, recipeid
   from cte 
   where row = 1 
   and r.id = @recipeId
```

Comment: I am trying with a cte. Bu this query seems not allowing to select the recipe ?

Comment: @codea the filter by recipe is `where r.id = 2` this selects recipe 2, if you want a different recipe change change the 2 to the id you want to select?

Comment: @codea I've updated my answer to include declaring a variable to hold the recipe id you are looking for. If you don't want to filter at all just remove `and r.id=@recipeId`

Comment: thanks it works, I had an issue with r.id, I was using the c.recipeId instead !  And what if I need the default values ? Should I make another query ?

Comment: That should include the default values?

Comment: Yes you are right.  I was having data where equipment was not unique and this caused me some problems. Thanks Bob :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  cd.*
FROM    configurationData cdd
WHERE   recipeId = 1
LEFT JOIN
        configurationData cda
ON      cda.equipment = cdd.equipment
        AND cda.recipeId = 2
JOIN    configurationData cd
ON      cd.id = COALESCE(cda.id, cdd.id)
```